# Convert flutter Image object to File object to send on server

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter ,I have a image object returned by signature pad and i want to send it to server which is accepting File so How can i send this object to server. OR how can we convert this image object to File in flutter.

```
Image _sign;
File _uplodfile;
final data = await signatureGlobalKey.currentState.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
final bytes = await data.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

if (data != null) {
  setState(() {
    _sign = Image.memory(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader).

Firstly stored it into phone, then convert it to File before send to server.

```
final data = await signatureGlobalKey.currentState.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
var savedDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = savedDir.path;

await Directory('$appDocPath/Signature/').create(recursive: true);
var file ='$appDocPath/image/${DateUtil().signformattedDate()}.png';
File(file).writeAsBytesSync(bytes.buffer.asInt8List());

submitToServer(file);
```

**submitToServer**

```
void submitToServer(String file) async {
    var savedDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = savedDir.path;
    var filename = FileUtils.basename(file);
    final taskId = await uploader.enqueue(
        url: "your upload link",
        files: [
          FileItem(filename: filename, savedDir: appDocPath, fieldname: "file")
        ],
        method: UploadMethod.POST,
        headers: {"apikey": "api_123456", "userkey": "userkey_123456"},
        data: {"name": "john"}, // any data you want to send in upload request
        showNotification:
            false, // send local notification (android only) for upload status
        tag: "upload 1"); // unique tag for upload task
  }
```

Comment: The getter 'buffer' isn't defined for the type 'Image'.
Try importing the library that defines 'buffer', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'buffer'. this error and

Comment: And I do not want multiple files to add in phone,only one file update each time when signature is updated

Comment: use `bytes` instead. I have edited my answer.